# OrgMode- autofit table column width to contents on HTML export

Tags: html, css, org-mode, column-width

I am trying to export an Org mode table to HTML, and it's adding a HUGE amount of space between each column so that I have to really scroll to the right to see the whole table. How can I set the table column width to automatically resize according to either cell contents or a percent of the window size?

I have searched forums high and low and not been able to find a solution, I really appreciate any help you could give me.

I have a screen shot that I am mot able to attach due to insufficient reputation points :(

Comment: Are you talking of spaces in columns of the Org buffer or in the exported HTML file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem I had was with conflicting code in the CSS file. So, if you are having this problem, I recommend checking your style sheet!

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking of spaces in the Org buffer, do C-c C-c to resize to the contents. If still too big, because of the contents itself, you can always add a "prefix" line with size specifiers (such as "<10>" to limit the visible width to 10 chars). See the doc.

If talking of HTML export, I'd suggest processing your HTML file with tidy, after the HTML export.

Comment: Thanks, I should have clarified more. The spacing issue occurs in table columns after exporting to HTML. Unfortunately, tidy is not something that is offered on our company server. Everything else is appearing properly, it's just the column spacing that is wonky.

Comment: Can't help more, only modifying the export function would help, then. Ask maybe this on the ML, and see whether someone is ready to do it -- if you come with a strong use case.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what else I can figure out and post back if I figure it out.